# add or remove class based on value of PHP variable using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a profile page on which I show details about the author of site. Site have different authors and moderators. Profile Page has three social media buttons which have links to social media accounts of the author of the site. I fetch social media links from SQL database using PHP. Php is working fine. I want if no link to any social media account, then add `hidden` class to that social media button using Jquery.

I tried this but not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var facecook = '<?php echo $facebook; ?>';
  if (facebook < 0) {
    $('.facebook').addClass('hidden')
  };
  var google = '<?php echo $google; ?>';
  if (google > 0) {
    $('.google').removeClass('hidden')
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <a href="" class="btn facebook">
    <?php echo $facebook; ?>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="btn twitter">
    <?php echo $twitter; ?>
  </a>
  <a href="" class="btn google-plus">
    <?php echo $google; ?>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just do that directly in the div tag?

Comment: Note 1 ... What is the value of $facebook and $google?
Note 2 ... `if (facebook < 0)` and `if (google > 0)`? Is that right?
Note 3 ... there is no `$('.google')` ... but there is `$('.google-plus')`

Comment: First off, the class for Google is `google-plus` while you're trying to add the hide class to `.google`. Second, why not just set the hidden class directly in the HTML? Or better yet, simply don't output the HTML for the social buttons that are missing.

Comment: FROM `var facecook = '<?php echo $facebook; ?>';` TO `var facebook = <?php echo $facebook; ?>;`

Comment: @EmptyBrain - Since we actually don't know what those variables contains, I would go with the quotes. If they are numbers, the code will still work (JS being a loosely typed language and all).

Comment: check it.`not empty and isInteger`. [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isInteger)

Comment: @neokio  $facebook and $google have links of social media accounts of the person.

Comment: thansk to all for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script. Typo error in your code.

`var facecook = '<?php echo $facebook; ?>';` to `var facebook = '<?php echo $facebook; ?>';`

`facebook` not `facecook`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var facebook = '<?php echo $facebook; ?>';

  if (facebook=='') {     
    $('.facebook').addClass('hidden')
  };
  var google = '<?php echo $google; ?>';
  if (google == '') {
    $('.google').removeClass('hidden')
  }
});
```